# I want to retrieve subdocument which matches with query

Tags: mongodb

Please refer the following document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("594b9eb9e1b22e09f8af00ee"),
    "Name" : "Master List",
    "UserId" : ObjectId("594b9eb9e1b22e09f8af00ed"),
    "Items" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59485d9d0fd04d1294e06766"),
            "Title" : "Muscle Milk Protein",
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59485d9d0fd04d1294e06772"),
            "Title" : "Baby Macro Organic 120g",
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59485d9d0fd04d1294e06780"),
            "Title" : "Fruit Bread Soft Strap",
        }
    ]
}
```

From the above document, I want results based on the search string For eg: "/.*Mus.*/" I should get the following result, but I am getting entire Items details as above

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("594b9eb9e1b22e09f8af00ee"),
    "Name" : "Master List",
    "UserId" : ObjectId("594b9eb9e1b22e09f8af00ed"),
    "Items" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59485d9d0fd04d1294e06766"),
            "Title" : "Muscle Milk Protein",
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried the following queries but none of this fetches the matched title from Items subdocument

**Query1:** `db.getCollection('List').find({'UserId': new ObjectId("594b9eb9e1b22e09f8af00ed"), 'Items': {'$elemMatch': {'Title': <code>{$regex:'.*uscle. *'}}}})`

**Query2:** `db.getCollection('List').find({'UserId': new ObjectId("594b9eb9e1b22e09f8af00ed"), 'Items.Title': <code> {$regex:'.*Mus. *'}})`

Can you please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/), "unpack", the nested array.

```
db.getCollection.aggregate([
    {
      $unwind:"$Items"
    },
    {
      $match: {
        "Items.title": {
          regex: /yourPattern/
        }
      }
    }
])
```

Hope it helps! Aggregation is truly awesome in MongoDB.

Comment: Is there any chance to accommodate same logic in find()?

Comment: I am afraid not. Is there a reason you want  to use find?

Comment: No specific reason. Just wanted to know if this can be achieved using find(), if yes can you please help?

I tried following query pattern for my requirement, seems working fine.

db.getCollection('List').aggregate({ $unwind:"$Items" }, { $match: { "Items.Title": { $regex: '.*Mus.*' }}}, { $match: { "UserId": new ObjectId( "594b9eb9e1b22e09f8af00ed" ) }})

Comment: Glad to see that `$unwind` is working for you. I have no idea how you could get the same result with `find()`, maybe with `forEach()`, but I am just geussing. As for your query, you can use `$and` with `$match`: `db.getCollection('List').aggregate([{ $unwind: "$Items" }, { $match: {$and: [{ "Items.Title": { $regex: '.*Mus.*' }}, { "UserId": new ObjectId( "594b9eb9e1b22e09f8af00ed" )}]}}])` (I hope I got all the parantheses).